# How does project with nested node_modules behave?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

We are trying to separate our project into "sub modules" within single repo, but keep things like webpack, express server global, so assume structure like this

```
package.json
server.js
index.js
node_modules/
public/
  index.html
  dashboard.js
  onboarding.js
dashboard/
  index.js
  package.json
  node_modules/
  components/
  assets/
onboarding/
  index.js
  package.json
  node_modules/
  ...
```

idea here is to keep build / routing / server logic at root lvl and separate modules like `dashboard` and `onboarding` into their separate folders and allow them to use their own node modules.

Will this work? Will node modules be included correctly?

webpack will build assets to `public/` folder, with some vendor assets and several entry points i.e. all `index.js` files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are proposing will work fine and compile as you expect. NodeJS will initially look for modules included in your modules 'node_modules' sub-directory and then work up the ladder.